# UILabel set dynamic Text including a long long

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi i am trying to set a UILabeltext with the remaining KB Left from a NSURLConnection Download.

```
NSString *left = (@"Remaining: %lli KB", (exceptedBytes-resourceLength)/1024);
[kbeleft setText:left];
```

But it does not work. But when i am trying to use NSLog with

```
NSLog(@"Remaining: %lli KB", (exceptedBytes-resourceLength)/1024);
```

it works without any problems

what i am doing wrong?

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%lli` isn't a valid String Format Specifier

Supported String Format Specifiers with `stringWithFormat`

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to use:

```
stringWithFormat:
```

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/